# href and ng-click in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I have this line at the code:

```
<a href="/blabla/topQues.html#{{m}}"data-ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); getQues()"></a>
```

The function getQues() pars the URL and do somthing, But the getQues() call befre the URL really changed.

What can i do to solve it?

Comment: Yes when event fires it happens by click  you may need to use it bit different  way like calling the Route inside the ng-click functioned controller buy  $location.path('/blabla/topQues.html#{{m}}'); like that

Comment: The line of code you have re4turn above will call the function getQues() before changing the url because if prevent default
What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {

    var url = $location.path();
    $scope.getQues(); // you can pass url to this function

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your html a bit, pass the URL as a parameter to your getQues() function. Do

Do the parsing and other work in your function, then go to the desired url using $location.path("url")

If you want to keep the href attribute in the html tag, use ng-href instead of href

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

```
<a ng-href="/blabla/topQues.html#{{m}}" data-ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); getQues()"></a>
```